# Ruby Soap4R Web Service, .NET Consumer

Tags: ruby, web-services, soap4r

How do I generate WSDL from a Web Service in Ruby using Soap4R (SOAP::RPC::StandaloneServer) that would be consumed from .NET?

Comment: see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599703/genrating-wsdl-in-ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599703/genrating-wsdl-in-ruby) for a good answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a way to do this through SOAP4R, unfortunately. SOAP4R is more for interacting with SOAP endpoints, or generating your own through a WSDL specification.

The only Ruby code I know that does this comes from ActionWebService, which was part of Rails, pre-Rails 2. If you install the gem `actionwebservice` (you'll have to force it, most likely), you can look at the method `to_wsdl` in the file `lib/action_web_service/dispatcher/action_controller_dispatcher.rb`. This builds WSDL using the Builder library. The definitions for the WSDL are defined using methods in `ActionWebService::API`. It should not be too hard to extract that code into something you can use for your project.