# How do I generate a WSDL using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, wsdl

I starting to work with Ruby and Soap and had some questions:

How do I generate a WSDL file for the service I created?
   Will it be compatible with an .NET client ?

---

```
begin
   class MyServer < SOAP::RPC::StandaloneServer
         # Handler methods
      def add(a, b)
         return a + b
      end
      def div(a, b)
         return a / b
      end

      # Expose our services
      def initialize(*args)
         add_method(self, 'add', 'a', 'b')
         add_method(self, 'div', 'a', 'b')
      end


  end
  server = MyServer.new("MyServer",
            'urn:ruby:calculation', 'localhost', 8080)
  trap('INT'){
     server.shutdown
  }
  server.start
rescue => err
  puts err.message
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ActionWebService (previously in Rails core, now a gem) has tools to generate WSDL files. You can use the tools even if you're not running your service within Rails.

http://www.datanoise.com/articles/2008/7/2/actionwebservice-is-back

As for whether it will work with a .NET client, the answer is maybe. Many .NET clients seem to expect Microsoft's "extended" SOAP info, which .NET webservices provide by default. If the client is also able to consume a service without that extra stuff, then sure.

#### UPDATE #1

The above link no longer appears to work. There are however forks of ActionWebService that have popped up over on github. You can see a pretty good list of them [here](https://github.com/search?q=actionwebservice&ref=commandbar). Here are a couple of links to some key versions:

- [original datanoise version](https://github.com/datanoise/actionwebservice)
- [clevertechru's port, works w/ Rails 3.1.* & Ruby 1.9](https://github.com/clevertechru/actionwebservice)

Comment: unfortunatelly, the link is down. the lastest copy I've found is http://web.archive.org/web/20091016212144/http://www.datanoise.com/articles/2008/7/2/actionwebservice-is-back